# Learn Python the Hard Way - Exercise 24

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

The extra credit question for [this exercise](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex24.html):

> Q: Why do you you call the variable `jelly_beans` but the name `beans`
>   later?
>
> A: That's part of how a function works. Remember that inside the
>   function the variable is temporary. When you return it then it can be
>   assigned to a variable for later. I'm just making a new variable named
>   `beans` to hold the return value.

What does *"the variable inside the function is temporary"* mean? Does that mean the variable is not valid after the `return`? It seems like after the indentation of the function, I can't print the variable used in the function part.

From the answer it says *"When you return it then it can be assigned to a variable for later"*. Could someone explain that sentence a bit please?

```
print "Let's practice everything."
print 'You\'d need to know \'bout escape with \\ that do \n newlines and \t tabs.' 


poem = """
\tThe lovely world
with logic so firmly planted
cannot discern \n the needs of love
nor comprehend passion from intuition
and requires an explanation
\n\t\twhere there is none.
"""

print "-------------"
print poem
print "-------------" 


five = 10 - 2 + 3 - 6 
print "This should be five: %s" % five 

def secret_formula(started):
    jelly_beans = started * 500 
    jars = jelly_beans / 1000 
    crates = jars / 100 
    return jelly_beans, jars, crates 


start_point = 10000 
beans, jars, crates = secret_formula(start_point) 

print "With a starting point of : %d" % start_point 
print "We'd have %d beans, %d jars, and %d crates." % (beans, jars, crates) 

start_point = start_point / 10 

print "We can also do that this way:" 
print "We'd have %d beans, %d jars, and %d crates." % secret_formula(start_point)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does that mean the variable is not valid after the `return`?

Yes; when the function ends all locally-scoped names (`jelly_beans`, in your example) cease to exist. The name `jelly_beans` is only accessible within `secret_formula`.

> It seems like after the indentation of the function, I can't print the variable used in the function part.

You cannot access them from outside the function, even via the function name (so neither `jelly_beans` nor `secret_formula.jelly_beans` give you access to the value). This is actually a good thing, as it means that you can *encapsulate* the internal logic within the function without exposing it to the rest of your program.

> From the answer it says *"When you return it then it can be assigned to a variable for later"*.

Only the local names inside the function are deleted, *not necessarily the objects they reference*. When you `return jelly_beans, jars, crates`, this passes the *objects* (not the *names*) back to whatever called `secret_formula`. You can give the objects the same names outside the function or something completely different:

```
foo, bar, baz = secret_formula(...)
```

[This article](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) is a useful introduction to how naming works in Python.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the scoping rules of Python, the name `jelly_beans` is valid only inside the `secret_formula` function. That is the reason you can not refer to it via a statement like `print jelly_beans` *outside* the function.

Notice that `secret_formula` returns a tuple to its caller. Therefore, when you type:

```
beans, jars, crates = secret_formula(start_point)
```

you specify a call to `secret_formula` (with a certain parameter), and assign the contents of the tuple to three different names.

- the returned value of `jelly_beans` is assigned to `beans`
- the returned value of `jars` is assigned to `jars`
- the returned value of `crates` is assigned to `crates`

In the latter two cases, it is important to note that even if the names are the same, the underlying objects may not be (not due to scoping rules, however - see the comments).

Comment: *"even if the names are the same, the underlying objects may not be"* - I'm not sure what you mean there. A Python function passes references to objects back to the caller, so they will be exactly the same objects.

Comment: I think when the lhs of an assignment is an object attribute, an overriden `__setitem__` could be performing something else entirely, e.g. assigning the name of a newly constructed object to the lhs.

Comment: That is true, but not what you've written and not applicable in this case.

Comment: True, it does not pertain to this specific question - clarified.