# Learn python the hard way ex24

Tags: python, python-2.x

I don't understand why `beans, jars, crates = secret_formula(start_point)` refers to `jelly_beans, jars, crates`.

This is the Ex24 from Learn python the hard way. Below I will put a answer from a Stackoverflow question with almost the same answer but didn't explain it fully so I really have a grasp of it.

```
print "Let's practice everything."

print 'You\'d need to know \'bout escape with \\ that do \n newlines and \t tabs.' 

poem = """ \tThe lovely world with logic so firmly planted cannot discern \n the needs of love nor comprehend passion from intuition and requires an explanation \n\t\twhere there is none. """

print "-------------"
print poem
print "-------------" 

five = 10 - 2 + 3 - 6

print "This should be five: %s" % five 

def secret_formula(started):
    jelly_beans = started * 500 
    jars = jelly_beans / 1000 
    crates = jars / 100 
    return jelly_beans, jars, crates 

start_point = 10000

beans, jars, crates = secret_formula(start_point)

print "With a starting point of : %d" % start_point
print "We'd have %d beans, %d jars, and %d crates." % (beans, jars, crates) 

start_point = start_point / 10 

print "We can also do that this way:"

print "We'd have %d beans, %d jars, and %d crates." % secret_formula(start_point)
```

This is the answer I found elsewhere:

[Learn Python the Hard Way - Exercise 24](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30164739/learn-python-the-hard-way-exercise-24)

Due to the scoping rules of Python, the name jelly_beans is valid only inside the secret_formula function. That is the reason you can not refer to it via a statement like print jelly_beans outside the function.
Notice that secret_formula returns a tuple to its caller. Therefore, when you type: beans, jars, crates = secret_formula(start_point) you specify a call to secret_formula (with a certain parameter), and assign the contents of the tuple to three different names.

- the returned value of jelly_beans is assigned to beans
- the returned value of jars is assigned to jars
- the returned value of crates is assigned to crates

Q: Why can't we call beans jelly_beans? Why can we with jars and crates?

I do understand that we get to 50000 by multiplying started * 1000.

However, why do we get that answer at:

```
print "We can also do that this way:"
print "We'd have %d beans, %d jars, and %d crates." % secret_formula(start_point)
```

Comment: Are you ok with this line: `print "We'd have%d beans, %d jars, and %d crates." % (beans, jars, crates)` ?

Comment: No. it should be have %d :) Sorry for late response, I am not used to using SO yet.

Comment: Pasting code here is a bit confusing at first, but I'm sure you'll soon get used to it. :) (But I'll fix that typo for you). However, the point of my question was: Do you understand what that line is doing?

Comment: In plain english, I think it tells python to print the formula as given in def secret_formula. With %d you make this an "open variable" in the string, with the % outside of this string you tell Python that he needs to do that part of formula / program at the %d's

Comment: `"We'd have %d beans, %d jars, and %d crates." %` expects a tuple of 3 numbers to slot into the string, one for each `%d`. You can supply that tuple like `(50, 10, 5)` or  `(beans, jars, crates)`, (assuming each of `beans`, `jars` & `crates` is a number). But you can also do `"We'd have %d beans, %d jars, and %d crates." % secret_formula(start_point)` because the `secret_formula` function returns a tuple of 3 numbers.

Comment: I didn't know the word Tuple. I understand now, from reading Wikipedia, that a tuple is a sequence. I don't really have a mathematical background so my own language is a bit different than from yours. I do my best to explain myself correctly :) Another lesson learned :)

Comment: Well, a `tuple` is one of the standard Python sequence types. It's similar to a `list` except that a tuple is immutable, which means that the items in a tuple can't be changed. You write a list with square brackets, but you write a tuple with round brackets, and in some cases you can leave the brackets out, which is what's happening in the `return` statement of `secret_formula`. And in this line: `beans, jars, crates = secret_formula(start_point)`

Comment: This all makes way more sense now. And any time you call secret_formula you will get that same formula back. You just need to name it differently: secret_formula(started)  .. secret_formula(start_point). Why is that?

Comment: `started` is the name that `secret_formula` uses internally. When you call it you can pass it a number, eg `secret_formula(42)`, or you can pass it any name that's bound to a number, like `start_point`. But we'd better stop here: SO comments are really _not_ a good place to have extended discussions!

Comment: Thank you so much. I just need to crack on with the next exercise. Then the next book :) I understand what I need to understand thusfar, until the rabit hole goes a bit deeper again.

Comment: Just be careful - Learn Python the Hard Way can be "Learn Python the so-hard-it's-not-really-possible-at-all Way" if you're not careful as you don't get some of the fundamental concepts (e.g. `tuple` as above).  There are other resources with tutorials that could be better ways to learn - see e.g. http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F .  There have been some [criticisms of LPTHW](http://sopython.com/wiki/LPTHW_Complaints)

Comment: That sounds dangerous. So far, I am enjoying my learning process. But learning the wrong things or missing crucial learning points.. well, that can be negatively vital!

Answer (score 3):

> Why can't we call beans jelly_beans? Why can we with jars and crates?

It is not true. you can call your variable whatever you want, even jelly_beans.

```
jelly_beans, jars, crates = secret_formula(10000)
```

but have it in mind that these variable have nothing to do with those inside your function.

BEST Way to learn is to do it.

Comment: Hi, I am actually practicing with it. But my biggest confusion comes from this Q: beans, jars, crates = secret_formula(start_point)      I have no idea how we are getting to 50k as an answer if 10000 = start_point.    Does beans still refer to Jelly_beans, is that what it is? And could we have called "beans" anything we like? Is that what you are saying? I am at work so can't really try it out. What confused me was: Due to the scoping rules of Python, the name jelly_beans is valid only inside the secret_formula function. That is the reason you can not refer to it via a statement..[ ]

Comment: @JohnSmith: The  integer object named `jelly_beans` inside the `secret_formula()` function gets returned to the main part of the script, where it gets the name `beans`. You _could_ give it the name jelly_beans in the main  part of the script if you want, but Zed is trying to show you how the names inside the function are local to that function, IOW the code outside of the function is oblivious to the names defined inside the function.

Comment: Got it. So it could have easily been Shop, Drop, Flop = secret_formula(start_point). At that point Shop would still refer to jelly_beans, drop to jars and flop to crates.

Comment: @JohnSmith: You got it!

Comment: One question. What would happen if we had two "defs". Would python still understand what to capture from which? Going from the inside out, picking which def comes first, and then to the second etc?

Comment: @Nz1: I _think_ you're asking what happens if a function is defined inside another function. The innermost function can read variables defined in outer scopes, but it can't (normally) modify them, and if it tries to, a new local variable of that name gets created instead. And the outer function can't even see the variables defined in the inner function. But I suspect that this may be getting a bit too advanced for your current learning level, and I don't want to confuse you. :)